# React Stripe - Map State to Props on a stripe injected component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to connect my redux store to my CheckoutForm which I have setup in react following the strip docs. I want to be able to access redux and dispatch items but I am unsure how to proceed. How do I connect the code below?

**CheckoutForm.js**

```
...
   render() {

      const {stripe} = this.props;
      const {postal, name, paymentMethod, errorMessage} = this.state;

      return (
        <div>
          { this.state.showPay ? 

          <button onClick={this.payWithCard}>
            Pay with stored card
          </button>
          :
          <form onSubmit={this.SaveCard}>
            <CardSection />
          <button>Save Card</button>
          </form>
          }
        </div>
        
      );
    }
  }

  export default function InjectedCheckoutForm() {
    return (
      <ElementsConsumer>
        {({ stripe, elements }) => (
          <CheckoutForm stripe={stripe} elements={elements} />
        )}
      </ElementsConsumer>
    );
  }
```

Usually I would do something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const { reducer } = state
     return { reducer }
   };

   const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
       storePaymentIntent: (y) => dispatch({ type: "PAYMENT_INTENT", value: y })
     };
   };
  
   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(CheckoutForm);
```

I have tried the following but it seems I can only pull the initial reducer not once its values have changed.

```
import ourReducer from './store/reducer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const store = createStore(ourReducer);
...
console.log(store.getState().reducer); //GIVES ME NULL VALUES*******
  export default function InjectedCheckoutForm() {
    return (
      <ElementsConsumer>
        {({ stripe, elements }) => (
          <CheckoutForm stripe={stripe} elements={elements} />
        )}
      </ElementsConsumer>
    );
  }

  store.subscribe(InjectedCheckoutForm);
```

Comment: I'm a little lost as to what you're after with the `store.subscribe(InjectedCheckoutForm)` call. Generally speaking all that's needed would be for you to connect the InjectedCheckoutForm to Redux. You could also connect the CheckoutForm itself if you prefer. From there you should be able to dispatch actions and the component will automatically subscribe to state updates. From the code you shared you aren't dispatching any actions to update the state so its expected that the values you get back are all `null` right?

Comment: They were values set in a different component so they weren't supposed to be null. Either way figured it out below. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was able to access Redux store values by doing the following:

```
...
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     const { reducer } = state
     return { reducer }
   };
   
   const mapDispachToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
       storePaymentIntent: (y) => dispatch({ type: "PAYMENT_INTENT", value: y })
     };
   };

   const InjectedCheckoutForm = (props) => (
    <ElementsConsumer>
        {({ stripe, elements }) => (
            <CheckoutForm 
            stripe={stripe} elements={elements}  {...props}
            />
        )}
    </ElementsConsumer>
  );
  
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispachToProps)(InjectedCheckoutForm);
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver